# pthread_cond_timedwait() not working on FreeBSD, returns EPERM

Tags: unix, pthreads, freebsd

I have a sample program which creates a pthread, waits for the thread to join. The thread will invoke phread_cond_timedwait() to wait for 2 seconds. On Linux platforms, the sample code works fine. On FreeBSD, the call returns immediately with EPERM error code.

### pthread_condition_timedwait.cpp

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

void *thread_handler(void *ptr){
  pthread_cond_t cond  = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
  pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

  struct timespec ts;
  struct timeval tp;

  gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);

  ts.tv_sec  = tp.tv_sec;
  ts.tv_nsec = tp.tv_usec*1000;
  ts.tv_sec += 2;

  //Invoke pthread_cond_timedwait() to wait for 2 seconds
  int rcode = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &ts);

  if (rcode == ETIMEDOUT)
    printf("Terminated due to time out\n");
  else if (rcode == EPERM)
    printf("Terminated due to EPERM\n");
  else
    printf("Return code is %d\n", rcode);

  return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv){
  pthread_t thread;

  // start the thread
  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &thread_handler, NULL);

  // wait for thread to finish
  pthread_join(thread, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Yaswanth T Try locking the mutex first.

Comment: @Erik Alapää Thank you. It works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EPERM is returned if the thread that calls timedwait does not own the mutex. You must lock the mutex before calling timedwait. Also, move the static initialization of mutex and condvar to file scope.

UPDATE: If you initialize the mutex to be an error-checking mutex, Linux will also terminate with EPERM (since it is UB to call pthread_cond_wait/timedwait without holding the mutex).

Modified code  below:

```
//#define _BSD_SOURCE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;


void *thread_handler(void *ptr){

    struct timespec ts;
    struct timeval tp;

    gettimeofday(&tp, NULL);

    ts.tv_sec  = tp.tv_sec;
    ts.tv_nsec = tp.tv_usec*1000;
    ts.tv_sec += 2;

    //Invoke pthread_cond_timedwait() to wait for 2 seconds                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
    int rcode = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &ts);

    if (rcode == ETIMEDOUT)
        printf("Terminated due to time out\n");
    else if (rcode == EPERM)
        printf("Terminated due to EPERM\n");
    else
        printf("Return code is %d\n", rcode);

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){

    pthread_mutexattr_t mta;
    pthread_mutexattr_init(&mta);
    pthread_mutexattr_settype(&mta, PTHREAD_MUTEX_ERRORCHECK);

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &mta);

    pthread_t thread;

    // start the thread                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &thread_handler, NULL);

    // wait for thread to finish                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Tested on kernel SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux, distro Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid.

Comment: Works with the mutex locked. Wonder why it passes on Linux though.

Comment: Yes, calling cond_wait/timedwait without locking the mutex is weird, and is also UB. From the manpage http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/pthread_cond_wait.html: The pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_timedwait() functions are used to block on a condition variable. They are called with mutex locked by the calling thread or undefined behaviour will result. Maybe if you turn on error-checking mutexes Linux will signal an error.